# detect which port a usb stick is connected to

Tags: linux, usb

Due to hardware layout issues, `USB port 1` on an embedded device is experiencing grave difficulties. Therefore, I would like users to use `USB port 2` instead. Is there anyway to check which port an external USB device is connected to?

Please note, the embedded device is running a minimal Linux Kernel and does not possess some tools / does not support some commands such as `lsusb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try exploring `/sys/bus/usb/devices/`.

Comment: When connected to usb port 1,it creates the directory `/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/2-1` and when connected to port 2, it creates `/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/1-1`